# What is thet difference between venison and veal?

Tags: veal, venison

What is the difference between venison and veal? I often read about these two things but I'm left wondering what these two things are and what the difference is between the two.

Comment: I'm a little tempted to close this as unclear what you're asking - surely you're looking for more than "they are from different animals", or did you just not bother looking it up?

Comment: I'm rather staggered that such a poorly received question could have 17k views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Venison is deer meat. It typically has a flavor similar to beef but it is stronger. While I have not had any that tastes wild or gamey, I have heard that some cuts do taste that way.

Veal is calf (very young cow). It has a very mild flavor, not at all like beef from a grown cow or bull. Some people substitute pork for veal in certain recipes as the taste is closer than beef.

Answer (score 3):

Venison is the meat of a deer, whereas veal is the meat of a young cow (calf) which has typically been fed on milk only or a mixture of milk and regular feed.

In terms of differences, venison is a rich, gamey meat, and veal is a pale-coloured, very tender beef.

Hope that helps, but in future I would recommend searching online for an answer as this question could have easily been answered there.